# quartz spring boot with oracle DB

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I have decided to go with quartz with data base option. I configured a simple job and deployed my changes. These changes are reflected in oracle quartz tables. The table **QRTZ_TRIGGERS** recorded the trigger name and trigger type as SIMPLE. I wanted to update the simple job to a cron job and I made those changes in spring configuration. Local is working as expected. When I deployed the changes to dev, build went successfully. **QRTZ_TRIGGERS** **did not** reflect these changes. The trigger type still shows as SIMPLE. I'm expecting this to be updated by spring on load and create a record in **QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS** and delete the entries in **QRTZ_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS**

This is not happening. Is there a prop that I can add in spring configuration so that these changes will be picked up when the server starts (for first time)?

Answer (score 0):

**overwriteExistingJobs** set this prop to true in

setOverwriteExistingJobs
public void setOverwriteExistingJobs(boolean overwriteExistingJobs)
Set whether any jobs defined on this **SchedulerFactoryBean** should overwrite existing job definitions. Default is "false", to not overwrite already registered jobs that have been read in from a persistent job store.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.